# How relevant is retina.js to my web projects?

Tags: website-design, front-end-development

I am currently not using a Mac for my work, but I came across [retina.js](http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/) while surfing the web. I would like to know if it is necessary to include this library into my web projects? If I don't, would my projects look good on all Mac devices?  I currently do not have any issues with work on other devices. I have not previewed it on any apple device yet, as it is still a work in progress.

Comment: For what it's worth, retina.js doesn't directly relate to Apple devices. It's about high-[DPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) screens (= more than one real pixel per virtual px), which includes most smartphones, a decent amount of laptops and even some desktop monitors today. Apple just coined the term "retina" for their high-DPI monitors.

Answer (score 15):

## Not even remotely required

It looks like it's primary purpose is to automatically do the work of [`srcset`](https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/), an attribute that allows you to specify images for different screen profiles, such as the high-density of Apple's "retina" screens.

`srcset` is trivial to use and doesn't requirement much extra work on your part. In my opinion, everyone should learn how to use `srcset` appropriately anyway.

In my opinion, there are several compelling reasons *not* to use this library.

- You can do what it does on your own
- It's yet-another-script to fire on your page, which slows your page
- It breaks the intended accessibility of `srcset` (allowing the browser and user to determine how to use the information in srcset, rather than you selecting what to load)

**Edit**

It is also worth mentioning that several browsers allow you to assign pixel density and other responsive settings using dev tools. For example, Chrome has [Device Mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3). These are useful for seeing if features like `srcset` (or retina.js, if you did chose to use that library) are actually working as expected. So you don't need to hunt down or a fancy-pants Mac for testing purposes.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. I will look into srcset

Comment: @ogeh_47 If this answered your question, can you please accept it? If not, let me know what additional information you need.

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys. It is much clearer to me now